# Android: Get Dataset ID from cursor populated Spinner

Tags: android, database, cursor, spinner

I'm using a spinner to let the user choose a database relation (1:n) in an create and update dialog. Populating the spinner with a database cursor works fine:

```
    //set up spinner
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.field_task_fkbudget);
    //set up cursor
    budgetsData = new TBTsqlHelperBudgets(this);        
SQLiteDatabase db = budgetsData.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c2 = db.query(TBTsqlHelperBudgets.TABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null);        
    c2.moveToFirst();
    // populate spiner
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c2, new String[] {TBTsqlHelperTasks.KEY_NAME}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
    spinner.setSelection(0);
```

My problem now is saving the choice to the database. I tried to use:

```
    ... 
    caller.updateTask(task_id, field_name.getText().toString(), s.getSelectedItemPosition());
    ...
```

but this gives me the datasets position within the spinner. What I need is the content of the field BaseColumns._ID of the cursor element that has been chosen in the spinner.

Is there a better way to receive this than doing another select with a string match on the database?

Answer (score 0):

Set an `OnItemSelectedListener` for the `Spinner` and inside the method

```
onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int pos, long id)
```

You have the `id` of the selected item, save this `id` in a class level variable

(lets say: `long selectedId`) and then when saving Choice in database

```
caller.updateTask(task_id, field_name.getText().toString(), selectedId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found a nice solution:

```
caller.updateTask(task_id, field_name.getText().toString(),s.getItemIdAtPosition(s.getSelectedItemPosition()));
```